# NHL Lottery - Figuring out % chance at top 3 pick

Tags: probability

The NHL has changed their draft lottery system this year to match the NBA's, sort of. The first 3 picks are up for lottery, with weighted odds based on standings.

I run a site that simply just simulates the lottery. Easy enough to figure out the odds of winning each pick individually, but a popular question is before anything happens, whats the chance to win one of the three lotteries.

Heres how it's set up:

```
| Position | Chances / 1000 | % Chance |
|----------|----------------|----------|
| 1        | 200            | 20%      |
| 2        | 135            | 13.5%    |
| 3        | 115            | 11.5%    |
| 4        | 95             | 9.5%     |
| 5        | 85             | 8.5%     |
| 6        | 75             | 7.5%     |
| 7        | 65             | 6.5%     |
| 8        | 60             | 6%       |
| 9        | 50             | 5%       |
| 10       | 35             | 3.5%     |
| 11       | 30             | 3%       |
| 12       | 25             | 2.5%     |
| 13       | 20             | 2%       |
| 14       | 10             | 1%       |
```

So say position 1 wins, it's 200 chances are in essence removed, resulting in position 2's chance to win the 2nd draw 135 / 800

However, if position 14 wins, position 2's chance at the 2nd draw become 135 / 990. The potential difference is compounded again for the third pick.

I'm not sure how to go about solving a chance at top 3 factoring in all possibilities of who wins the first 2 picks. Hopefully my issue makes sense, and someone can provide some guidance

Thank you!